# DropDown List is empty when generating a view from the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I have an enum property in Car.

```
public class Car
{
   public TypeCar TypeCar { get; set; }
}
```

The enum is

```
public enum TypeCar
{
   petrol,
   diesel,
   electric   
}
```

When generating the CRUD with Visual Studio, I can see the values being displayed properly in Index, but when I want to create a new car, the drop down list generated is empty. Isn't it supposed to fill the values petrol,diesel,electric ?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="TypeCar" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="TypeCar" class="form-control"></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="TypeCar" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to specify the available select options list using the `asp-items` property. Your code only specifies the model property for the selected option (`asp-for`).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="TypeCar" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="TypeCar" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<TypeCar>()" class="form-control"></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="TypeCar" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>
```

Edited:
You should import your Enum class like @using TypeCar

Comment: Yes, tried it but it does not work. It says that the type or namespace could not be found. There's the @model BaseCompteursApp.Models.Car on the top and all my other fields don't have that issue.

Comment: @TropicalViking as hinted in this answer, you are missing binding `asp-items` property in your `select`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

In your PageModel's OnGet() or OnGetAsync():

```
ViewData["CarTypes"] = new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(TypeCar)).Cast<TypeCar>().Select(s => s.ToString()).ToList());
```

In your View:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label asp-for="TypeCar" class="control-label"></label>
  <select asp-for="TypeCar" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CarTypes">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
  <span asp-validation-for="TypeCar" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```